# Memcpy func take Pointer variable? char *p; char* q; memcpy(p,q,10); will it work?

Tags: c, memcpy, memcmp

`Memcpy` and `memcmp` function can take a Pointer variable?

```
char *p;
char* q;
memcpy(p,q,10); //will this work?
memcmp(p,q,10); //will this work?
```

Comment: What stops you from trying it?

Comment: Yes if memory is allocated to your destination pointer

Comment: The first and second arguments to `memcpy` are pointers. What else did you expect them to be? Have you read the documentation for `memcpy`?

Answer (score 1):

No, your code as written will not work, since you're passing uninitialized pointers to `memcpy()` (and `memcmp()`, but the `memcpy()` call is enough). This will cause undefined behavior, since you're not allowed to read/write from those "random" locations.

You can fix it by making sure the pointers are valid, for instance:

```
char buf[10], *p = buf;
const char *q = "hello hello";

memcpy(p, q, 10);
printf("the copying made the buffers %s\n",
  memcmp(p, q, 10) == 0 ? "equal" : "different");
```

Of course `p` can be replaced by just plain `buf` above.

Comment: I understood but will this below work?char *p = "buf";
const char *q = "hello hello";

memcpy(p, q, 10);
printf("the copying made the buffers %s\n",
  memcmp(p, q, 10) == 0 ? "equal" : "different");

Comment: No, that's undefined behavior since string literals live in read-only memory. That's why I used a `char` array as the destination.

Comment: ok now it is very clear in case of memcpy() .. how about memcmp() in this too we need to use always at least one array argument?

Comment: @Dev You never need to use "at least one array argument", no. Not with `memcpy()` either, that's not the issue. You just need the address of memory that you're allowed to access (write, in the case of `memcpy()`'s first argument, or read in the remaining three cases). Whether or not the memory comes from an array or not doesn't matter, and the called function has *no way* of knowing this. It's just memory.